# numpy sort error in complie with numba jit decorator

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am trying to implement numba.jit function to call numpy.sort function to sort a numpy array, but it fails as "Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected". My code is below:

```
gg = numpy.array ([[1,0,2],[1,2,1]],dtype = np.dtype((int,int)))

@nb.jit(nb.void(numba.int32[:,:]))
def kk (gg):
    np.sort(gg)
```

I have also tried njit mode but also got error as:

```
"Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
   [1m[1m[1mNo implementation of function Function(<intrinsic stub>) found for signature:

    >>> stub(array(int32, 2d, A))

   There are 2 candidate implementations:
   [1m  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
     Intrinsic of function 'stub': File: numba\core\overload_glue.py: Line 35.
       With argument(s): '(array(int32, 2d, A))':"
```

I have checked the numba documentation as it shows the numpy.sort function is supported. Is there something wrong with my code? or does the sort function would only work in object mode?

Answer (score 1):

Numba does not support sorting two-dimensional arrays. To get around this, you can iterate over the dimension of interest and sort each row or column. *However, this will be slower than using `np.sort` directly.*

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(nb.int32[:, :](nb.int32[:, :]))
def sort_by_second_axis(arr):
    # Make a copy so we do not modify original.
    arr = arr.copy()
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        arr[i].sort()
    return arr
```

And here is an example of use:

```py
prng = np.random.RandomState(42)
x = (prng.uniform(size=16) * 10).astype("int32").reshape(4, 4)
np.array_equal(np.sort(x), sort_by_second_axis(x))
```

---

The warning disappears if you use `@nb.jit(nb.void(nb.int32[:]))` (i.e., apply this to a one-dimensional array). Numba doesn't seem to support `np.sort` on non-flat arrays with nopython mode. This is why it has to fall back to object mode.

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nb.void(nb.int32[:]))
def sortme(arr):
    np.sort(arr)
```

---

I would also question whether you need numba in this case. `np.sort` is implemented in C and is already compiled. It's very fast, and from my tests, numba is a bit slower.

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(nb.int32[:](nb.int32[:]))
def sort_numba(arr):
    return np.sort(arr)

prng = np.random.RandomState(seed=42)
x = (prng.rand(100_000) * 1_000).astype("int32")
assert np.array_equal(np.sort(x), sort_numba(x))

%timeit np.sort(x)
# 3.73 ms ± 45.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit sort_numba(x)
# 3.98 ms ± 37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi, I am having a multi dimensional array. not 1D.. I am trying to improve the speed on sorting my data, this is why I am trying to see if numba would do the job.

Comment: @user2625363 - please see my edits